# docker run ubuntu on mac and nothing happens

Tags: macos, docker

i'm on mac running:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

my-mac:mydir$ docker run ubuntu /bin/bash
my-mac:mydir$
```

am i doing something wrong? shouldn't I get into the `ubuntu` shell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By running `docker run ubuntu /bin/bash`, docker create a randomly-named container from the image ubuntu and runs a `bash` without `stdin`, `stdout` nor `stderr` then `bash` exits (right after being started).

Try at least to set a tty and interactive mode (aka [foreground mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground)):

```
 docker ps -a
 # if not exited, stop it first
 docker stop <container_id>
 # remove the container which cannot be used
 docker rm <container_id>

 # let's try again
 docker run -it --rm --name=test ubuntu bash
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740858/docker-run-ubuntu-on-mac-and-nothing-happens/35740904#comment78857109_35740904) by [physincubus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3642371/physincubus):

> - '`-it`' is the bit that makes it interactive,
> - '`--rm`' removes the container when you exit (so if you want to be able to exit for detach and reattach later, do not do this), and
> - '`--name`' allows you to name the container more explicitly in case you want to run multiple instances of the same container

Comment: @Auzias Thenk you for the edit. The fact that bash was exiting was so obvious to me (without interactive mode) that I did not mention it.

Comment: I got that part without any doubt as the answered was from you! But as the question was about the "something wrong" I thought it would be more helpful to @Jas

Comment: just to explain a bit further for anyone who stumbles here '-it' is the bit that makes it interactive, '--rm' removes the container when you exit (so if you want to be able to exit for detach and reattach later, do not do this), and '--name' allows you to name the container more explicitly in case you want to run multiple instances of the same container

Comment: @physincubus Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Run it with following command

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Then you will get bash prompt of ubuntu container

Comment: How is this any better than the 2016 answer?